# undefined operator after quickload lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The function find-data-from-command works fine when I run it without first doing the 'quickload' of the  package. If I load the package it gives the error that split-sequence is undefined.

I have tried to reload split-sequence after loading the custom package. Doesn't work

```
(ql:quickload :<a-custom-package>)

(defun find-data-from-command (x desired-command)
  (setq desired-data ())
  (loop for line = (read-line x nil)
    while (and line (not desired-data)) do 
        (progn 
          (setq commands (first (split-sequence ":" line)))
          (setq data (split-sequence "," (first (rest (split-sequence ":" line)))))
          (print (cons "command:" commands))
          (cond
                ((equal commands desired-command) (return-from find-data-from-command data))))))
FIND-DATA-FROM-COMMAND

SIGMA 24 > 
  (setq obj-type (find-data-from-command (open "log.txt") "types"))

Error: Undefined operator SPLIT-SEQUENCE in form (SPLIT-SEQUENCE ":" LINE).
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is nothing to do with Quicklisp, it's to do with a package you've defined somewhere called `SIGMA`.  In particular somewhere in your code is a form which looks like:

```
(defpackage "SIGMA"                     ;or :sigma or :SIGMA or #:sigma or ...
  ...
  (:use ...)
  ...)
```

And then later

```
(in-package "SIGMA")
```

And the problem with this is that your package definition has an explicit `(:use ...)` clause.

[`defpackage`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpkg.htm), and the underlying function [`make-package`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_pkg.htm#make-package) has slightly interesting behaviour for the `:use` clause (or keyword argument in the case of `make-package`):

- if none is given then there is an *implementation-defined* default;
- if one is given then it overrides the default.

The idea, I think, is that implementations may want to provide a bunch of additional functionality which is available by default, and this functionality can't be in the `CL` package since the contents of that package is defined in the standard.  So if you just say

```
(defpackage "FOO")
```

Then the implementation is allowed (and, perhaps, encouraged), to make the use-list of `FOO` have some useful packages in it.  These packages might be the same ones that are in the default use-list of `CL-USER`, but I'm not sure that's required: the whole thing is somewhat under-specified.

The end result of this is that if you want to define packages which both make use of implementation-defined functionality *and* have explicit use-lists you have to resort to some slight trickery.  How you do this is slightly up to you, but since you are by definition writing implementation-dependent code where you are defining packages like this, you probably want to make it clear that what you are doing is implementation-dependent, by some form like

```
(defpackage :foo
  (:use ...)
  #+LispWorks
  (:use :lispworks :harlequin-common-lisp :cl)
  ...)
```

Or, if you just want some particular set of symbols

```
(defpackage :foo
  (:use ...)
  #+LispWorks
  (:import-from :lispworks #:split-sequence))
```

Note that this is not quite the same thing as using a package containing the symbol.

In all these cases if your code has pretensions to be portable then there should be appropriate clauses for other implementations and a way of knowing when you're trying to run on an implemention you haven't yet seen: how to do this is outwith the scope of this answer I think.

Comment: what the default used packages are or if there are any is undefined in the standard. SBCL uses none, then.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The quickloading of the custom package was taking me into the package. I did not realize that. So I had to specify split-sequence is from outside. So, I replaced all occurrences of split-sequence in the function definition with

`LISPWORKS:split-sequence`

Then it worked.

If any one has a better solution, please do let me know. Thanks

Comment: quickload loads systems, not packages. Your custom system should declare its depenndencies and define one or more custom packages. Your package might ":use" split-sequence so that it does not need to fully qualify its symbols. A lisp file should almost always start with an in-package form. See example code in your quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software directory or github.